# Dagger 2: How properly to reuse dependency - how to design components and scopes?

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2

in my app I have 3 activities: LoginActivity, PreferencesActivity and LoggedActivity.

The flow can be:

- **1)** LoginActivity -> PreferencesActivity (user can open preferences from login activity)
- **2)** LoginActivity -> LoggedActivity -> PreferenceActivity (user can open preferences but since he's already logged, some prefs are hidden)

I want 3 scopes and 3 components:

- AppComponent with @AppScope (app-wide singletons)
- UserComponent with @UserScope (alive only when user is logged)
- other with @ActivityScope (scope for each activity only)

**UserComponent is going to be created after successful login and destroyed when user logs out. But I need that information in PrefActivity (flow 2)**

Now I don't know how to design all those components since in my PreferenceActivity I also need to know if user is logged in or not but I also want to let user to see all preferences when not logged in from LoginActivity.

How to combine both cases?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Make the `PreferenceActivity` depend on the `UserComponent`. Which also makes sense, since you are trying to get different behavior on a different (logged out) user.

Make your `UserModule` return an interface, e.g. `PreferencePresenter` and depending on whether there is an authenticated user you would either return `UserPreferencePresenter` or `DefaultPreferencePresenter`, which would show/hide the appropriate preferences.

Comment: But `UserComponent` is going to be created in `LoggedActivity` so the user has to be logged in. I want to be able open `PreferenceActivity` from `LoginActivity` as well. I have an idea that may be similar to yours ... It is that in `Application` class I would hold `UserComponent` reference that would be `null` if user is not logged in.